# CentOs DISMAN-EVENT-MIB_mteTrigger not fired when average load thresholds are breached

Tags: linux, centos, cpu, snmp

I'm using CentOS OS with the following SNMP config.

```
###### CPU load monitoring ########
load 12 10 5
monitor -r 60s -o laNames -o laErrMessage "laTable" laErrorFlag !=0
```

When I increase the load (using stress tool), I don't see the trap (Trap ID .1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.0.1) fired, even though the thresholds were breached. I was expecting to see the trap when system uptime shows the following.

```
Every 2.0s: uptime                     Wed Aug  2 13:44:26 2017
13:44:26 up  3:31,  2 users,  load average: 57.69, 17.79, 14.44
```

I also have Disk monitoring settings for which DISMAN_EVENT traps (Trap ID .1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.0.1) are getting generated when the threshold is crossed.

```
###### Disk monitoring ######
disk / 10%
disk /var 10%
monitor -r 10s DiskAlmostFull dskPercent > 80
monitor -r 10s DiskFull dskPercent > 95
```

Hence, I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

My [man snmpd.conf](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html#lbAX) says

> Note that there must be whitespace around the  OP  token.
>     A comparison  such  as  OID !=0 will not be handled correctly.

So try `laErrorFlag != 0`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, @meuh. Your suggestion fixed the problem.